# Stuck on orange screen while booting off USB

Tags: boot, server, system-installation, 20.04, bios

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 on my [Dell PowerEdge 1850](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/poweredge-1850), but the furthest I have gotten is an orange screen with a keyboard sign and (accessibility sign?) on. I downloaded the ISO from the [official website](https://ubuntu.com/download/server) (Option 2) and then used Rufus 3.13 to mount it to a USB-drive.

I have tried several things, but they are not worth listing since I am of the opinion that I am at fault. I do understand most of the things I have to do, but Linux is new to me and so is older hardware like the server I am using. If you need anymore information I'd be glad to provide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have had a graphics driver issue, I solved it by launching ubuntu in recovery mode and then updating the drivers. (Using another display adapter should also work...)